# Pandas - Grab value x from column a if column y contains b

Tags: python, pandas, tree

Hi there stack overflow community,

I'm trying to get a tree-hierarchy from the following dataframe:

```
  SP             VP     
0 --           king   
1 king         knight 1     
2 king         knight 2
3 knight 1     knight 3
```

In column 'SP' I've the superior and in 'VP' the underlying knight. I've filtered the column 'SP' so far that I got the top node (king). Now i want to get all the knights in column 'VP' underlying to the king in 'SP', than the selected knights as new superiors and their underlying knights and so on...

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

#define input
df1=pd.read_excel(r'path').fillna("@Null$tring").sort_values(by=['VP'])
#df1=pd.read_excel(r'path').fillna("@Null$tring").sort_values(by=['VP'])

SP1 = df1['SP'].tolist()
VP1 = df1['VP'].tolist()

VP2 = df1.reindex(['VP'])
#identifies the top node
root = []

#Grabs values in SP not present in VP.
root = pd.Index(df1["SP"]).difference(pd.Index(df1["VP"]))

#assigns the values in SP to the position in VP
df2 = df1[df1["SP"].isin(root)][["SP", "VP"]].reset_index(drop = True)

root2 = df2['SP'].tolist()

#dropping ALL duplicate values
sps = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['SP'])

#all available SPs
spss =sps['SP']


#check output
spss.to_excel(r'C:\Users\mallk\OneDrive\Desktop\Koenigswege\ProgrammingDell\Tree Structure\Test.xlsx')
#print(SP1)

df3 = df2['VP'].isin(df1['SP'])

df3 = df1[df1['VP'].isin(df2)][['SP', 'VP']].reset_index(drop = True)

df3 = df1.loc['SP'] = [df2['VP']]

print(df2['VP'])
print(df3)
```

My last attemps to match the superior(king) with the underlying knights were the following:

```
df3 = df2['VP'].isin(df1['SP'])

df3 = df1[df1['VP'].isin(df2)][['SP', 'VP']].reset_index(drop = True)

df4 = df1.loc['SP'] = [df2['VP']]
```

But none of them work, I'm stucked :/ Maybe someone has some inspiration for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want your desired output to look like. But here is maybe what you are looking to achieve. Grouping VP by SP and getting the group values.

```
df.groupby('SP').get_group('king')['VP'].values
```

Output:

```
array(['knight 1', 'knight 2'], dtype=object)
```

This one get the subordinates of king for example. You can further automate this if this is your desired output.

**EDIT**

Here is how to automate it and add it to a new column in the dataframe

```
dict_groups = {}
for x in df['SP'].unique():
   values = df.groupby('SP').get_group(x)['VP'].values
   dict_groups[x] = values

df['subordinate'] = df.SP.map(dict_groups)
```

Output

```
    SP  VP  subordinate
0   __  king    [king]
1   king    knight 1    [knight 1, knight 2]
2   king    knight 2    [knight 1, knight 2]
3   knight 1    knight 3    [knight 3, soldier]
4   knight 1    soldier [knight 3, soldier]
5   knight 2    soldier [soldier]
```

Comment: Could you give me a hint how you would automate it?

Comment: @AnthonyAdmin Sure. I have edited the answer.

Comment: So cool, this helps me a lot to understand the pandas methods. God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

excuse my English, with subordinate do you mean that the SP and VP columns belong to the same index?

If you want only certain rows to belong to the same index and others not, this is not possible. It must be the totalities of the columns that belong to the index.

For what purpose do you want them to be subordinated? maybe there are other ways to do it.

Anyway, to have two columns as an index is as easy as `df.set_index(['SP', 'VP'], inplace=True)`

You can always have another auxiliary dataframe with the rows that interest you filtered and add the index there (because it will be applied to the two columns in its entirety -without excluding rows-).

Comment: Hi, i wanted to say that i have a king (the top node of the hierarchy) in 'SP' and I want to get all the underlying knights  in 'VP', so i would get knight 1 and 2 from column 'VP' because they match with king in column 'SP'

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to this?
df[df["SP"]=="king"]

With this you will filter by the first element of the hierarchy

Comment: Yes, correct, but i dont know how to do it with a if loop with pandas, like if  df[df["SP"]=="king"], get me the value in 'VP'

Comment: Thank you for your help, i think i found a solution :)